# Postgresql rows to columns (UNION ALL to JOIN)

Tags: postgresql

Hello with this query I'm getting one result with four rows, how can I change it in order to get four named columns with their own result every one?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vehicles WHERE cus=1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE cus=1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vehicle_events WHERE cus=1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vehicle_alerts WHERE cus=1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT a.ct veh_count, b.ct user_count, c.ct event_count, d.ct alert_count
FROM
( SELECT COUNT(*) ct FROM vehicles WHERE cus=1 ) a,
( SELECT COUNT(*) ct FROM user WHERE cus=1 ) b,
( SELECT COUNT(*) ct FROM vehicle_events WHERE cus=1 ) c,
( SELECT COUNT(*) ct FROM vehicle_alerts WHERE cus=1 ) d;
```

Answer (score 2):

UNION *only* adds rows; it has no effect on the columns.

Columns, which define the "shape" of the row tuples, *must* appear as selected columns<sup>1</sup>.

For example:

```
 SELECT
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vehicles WHERE cus=1) as veh_count
     ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE cus=1) as user_count
     ..
```

---

<sup>1</sup> There are other constructs that can allow this, see [crosstab](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html) for example - but the columns are *fixed* by the query command. It takes dynamic SQL to get a variable number of columns.